# iTextSharp PDF embedded barcodes using tables. Unable to format to one page

Tags: c#, itext

I am creating a page of barcodes to fit onto onlinelabels.com  [(ol2050LP)](http://www.onlinelabels.com/Products/OL2050LP.htm#LabelSpecs).

I have successfully produced barcodes and also have them nicely displaying in the table as I would expect.

The problem I am having is that it seems there is some phantom header and footer on the page pushing the last 2 rows of barcodes of the page.

My results:

[image]

Below is my method:

```
 public void CreatePDF(List<BarcodeLib.Barcode.DataMatrix> listOfBarcodes)
        {
            if (listOfBarcodes.Count >= 1)
            {
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(13);
                document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                document.SetMargins(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.2505f, 0.2505f);

                try
                {
                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"test.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew));
                    document.Open();
                    foreach (BarcodeLib.Barcode.DataMatrix image in listOfBarcodes)
                    {
                        iTextSharp.text.Image dmatrix = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image.drawBarcodeAsBytes(), true);
                        dmatrix.SetDpi(300, 300);
                        dmatrix.ScaleAbsolute(37, 37);
                        table.AddCell(dmatrix);
                    }
                    document.Add(table);
                    document.Close();
                }
                catch (DocumentException de)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message);
                }
                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I this all of your code? Looking at your screenshot, your table's default cell padding seems different but that could just be my lack of coffee. Anyway, that code (with sample images of my own) works as expected for me with the table being top-aligned.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I top aligned the table with no success. The code provided is where all the iTextSharp happens... My images(barcodes) are generated with no padding, the assumption being that they fit exactly into the label (which they do left to right). It looks like there is plenty of room for at least one more row vertically on the first page. I just can't figure out what element is padding it.

Answer (score 1):

You should do that before you open the document:

```
Document document = new Document();
document.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
```

**UPDATE!**

than:

```
document.Open();
```

Here's how it works in my program:

[image: without SetMargins] [image: with SetMargins]

(Left)without SetMargins, (Right)with SetMargins

Comment: It seems you want to me change the properties of the Document object before I even initialize it?

I'm not sure how this is possible other than initializing the document object with the margin parameters. `Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER,0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)`

Comment: Sorry, I meant open the document after set margins: 

document.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
document.Open();